# XMLinvalide chars replacement C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string that is displayed in XML but in it I have some invalid chars like string
 `s = <root> something here <XMLElement>hello</XMLElement> somethig here too </root>`
 where XMLElement is a List like XMLElement = {"bold", "italic",...} .
What I need is to replace the `<` and `</` if followed by any of the XMLElements to be replaced by `&gt;` or `&lt;` depending on the cases.
The `<root>` is to keep
I have tried so far some regEx

```
 strAux = Regex.Replace(strAux, "bold=\"[^\"]*\"",
match => match.Value.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;"));
```

or

```
 List<string> startsWith = new List<string> { "<", "</"};
        foreach(var stw in startsWith)
        {
            int nextLt = 0;
            while ((nextLt = strAux.IndexOf(stw, nextLt)) != -1)
            {
                bool isMatch = strAux.Substring(nextLt + 1).StartsWith(BoldElement); // needs to ckeck all  the XMLElements
                //is element, leave it
                if (isMatch)
                {
                    //its not, replace
                    strAux = string.Format(@"{0}&lt;{1}", strAux.Substring(0, nextLt), strAux.Substring(nextLt +1, strAux.Length - (nextLt + 1)));
                }
                nextLt++;
            }
        }
```

Also tried

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement element = doc.CreateElement("root");
            element.InnerText = strAux;
            Console.WriteLine(element.OuterXml);
            strAux = element.OuterXml.Replace("&lt;root&gt;", "").Replace("&lt;/root&gt;", "");
            return strAux; But it will repeat the `<root>` too
```

But nothing worked like I suposed. Is there any different ideias .Thanks

Comment: If you use one of  `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` and there related classes to write the date it will translate invalid characters for you.

Comment: What you have is well-formed XML. Why do you want to escape the nested element?

Comment: Is the way that the text is displayed. It´s not in my control..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is well-formed XML, so you can use the XML APIs to help you:

Using LINQ to XML (which is generally the better API):

```
var element = XElement.Parse(s);

element.Value = string.Concat(element.Nodes());

var result = element.ToString();
```

Or using the older `XmlDocument` API:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(s);
var root = doc.DocumentElement;

root.InnerText = root.InnerXml;

var result = root.OuterXml;
```

The result for both is:

```
<root> something here &lt;XMLElement&gt;hello&lt;/XMLElement&gt; somethig here too </root>
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ATK0ev) for a demo.

Comment: It removes the begining <root> and the end </root> of the string

Comment: @hiitsme no, it doesn't? Check the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `XmlWriter` class.

Sample from the documentation:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
settings.CloseOutput = false;

// Create the XmlWriter object and write some content.
MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(strm, settings);
writer.WriteElementString("someNode", "someValue");
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your input is well-formed XML, but you want to escape some of the tags. The issue here is that there's no way for the code to know which tags are valid and which aren't.

One way to do this is to create a list of valid tags.

```
List<string> validTags = new List<string>() { "root", "..." };
```

Then use regex to pick out all instances of `<tag>` or `</tag>`and replace them if they're not in the list.

Another way which is faster and easier, but requires more information up front, is to create a list of tags which *aren't* valid.

```
List<string> invalidTags = new List<string>() { "XMLElement", "..." };
```

Simple string manipulation will do, now.

```
string s = GetYourXMLString();
invalidTags.ForEach(t => s = s.Replace($"</{t}>",$"&lt;{t}&gt;")
                          .Replace($"<{t}>",$"&lt;/{t}&gt;"));
```

The second way should really only be used if you know which foreign tags are making (or will ever make) an appearance. If not the first approach should be used. One clever possibility is to dynamically create the list of valid tags using reflection or a data contract so that changes to the XML spec will be automatically reflected in your code.

For example, if each element is a property of an object, you might get the list like this:

```
var validTags = typeof(MyObjectType).GetProperties()
                                    .Select(p => p.PropertyName)
                                    .ToList();
```

Of course, the property names likely won't be the actual tag names, AND often you'll want to only include certain properties. So you make an attribute class to designate the desired properties (let's call it `XMLTagName`) and then you can do this:

```
var validTags = typeof(MyObjectType).GetProperties()
                                    .Select(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<XMLTagName>()?.TagName)
                                    .Where(tagName => tagName != null) //gets rid of properties that aren't tagged
                                    .ToList();
```

Even with all that, you'll still committing the crime of string manipulation on raw XML. After all, the *best* real solution here is to figure out how to fix the incoming XML to actually contain the data you want. But if that's not a possibility, the above should do the job.

Comment: Using this solution  invalidTags.ForEach(t => s.Replace($"</{t}>",$"&lt;{t}&gt;").Replace($"<{t}>",$"&lt;/{t}&gt;")); How can I get the string with the replacement. Because the string s is not replaced.

Comment: There was a bug in my code. It needs to be `(t => s = s.Replace(`. I've fixed it in my answer.